# Database Programming

Tags: java, database

How can I limit the number of concurrent connections to a number of specific clients to a database more specifically on the SQLite database in java, is there a specific java  function i can override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLite is quite limited, however you can wrap the SQLite and create your own method which blocks it or just synchronize all the method

Comment: I want to limit the number of concurrent connections to the database  to two clients only

Comment: create an integer which will be a member of the wrapper, when new connection created and there are 2 users, throw an exception or call wait() on the thread until, and call notify when connection closed